# Require '@since' tag in each class Javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, checkstyle, pmd

I'd like to require each top-level class to have `@since` tag in Javadoc.

Is it possible to configure any existing Checkstyle, PMD, SonarQube or IntelliJ IDEA inspection to validate that?

Comment: You can write your own checkstyle rules.

Comment: While this is far from foolproof, you could make a [regexp check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#Regexp) that requires the presence of `^\s*\*\s+@since\s+\S+`.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, I know. However the question is about solutions that are ready to use.

Comment: Well, you have looked in the documentation, and you didn't find one.  And if you are asking us to find / recommend a 3rd-party checkstyle rule ... that is off-topic.

Comment: @StephenC Checkstyle is highly-configurable tool while documentation for it doesn't describe all possibilities. I'm not asking to look for some third party solution - I'm more interested how can I configure existing rules. Same goes for PMD - it has e.g. possibility to configure rules by XPaths.